# ConstraintLayout properties tab missing

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I decided to try the new ContraintLayout, but the `properties` tab is missing.

I am using AndroidStudio 2.3, ConstraintLayout 1.0.2.

Is there any way to turn it on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. Switching to the design view (not the text view) of the layout editor and clicking on a specific view did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can open it by opening properties tab on the right side.
[image]

Comment: i would if i had it. it's simply not there for some reason

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who faces the same issue, here's the solution that worked for me:

1) open SDK manager

2) remove `ConstraintLayout for Android` and `Solver for ConstraintLayout` under `SupportRepository`

3) click apply/ok

4) add the same items again, click apply/ok, wait for installation to complete

5) profit

Comment: 5th step is the most important